Azure Front-door TCP_MISS even with Cache-Control: public
The Azure Front-door honours the cache headers from origin, so I can see the
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=1500

but then, underneath, the X-cache header is always TCP_MISS, what am I missing?
X-Cache: TCP_MISS

Edit: adding a screenshot from Postman

Edit 2: screenshot from Origin url:


Make sure your caching rule is configured properly. Ensure your path pattern and HTTP method conditions are being met for your Postman request. Use the SETIFMISS caching behaviour.

@ArchitectJamie it's just one checkbox that says Enable Caching and that's it. The docs say that it will honour the cache headers from origin, that's why we see Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=1500 - these are set at origin. So, not sure what else should be setup at Frontdoor?

What have you set your query string behavior to? There is this MS doc you can refer to- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-caching?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#query-string-behavior

@Arko set it to cache every query string individually (the option is called: Use Query String). But the url I am testing with, has no query string at all.

You can create individual caching rules. Your screenshot doesn't show your request, so it's a bit difficult to help. If it's a POST with some body content then it won't be cached. What is the webserver delivering? Is it dynamic or static content?

@ArchitectJamie it is a get request. It is an html document, origin sets the Cache-Control header to public as seen on the screenshot, but why is Front Door saying TCP_MISS, even if I repeat the same get request multiple times? Every time it says TCP_MISS

do a cache control of origin and share the screenshot of the output. Your screenshot is for AFD

@Arko - updated the question with a second screenshot.
